# Make prev and next arrows stick to edges of image in slideshow

Tags: css, position, slideshow, react-slideshow-image

I see there are several posts related to prev and next buttons w/ slideshows, but none specific to this issue. I used W3School template for how to create a slideshow and carousel. They place the prev and next arrows on the edge of the div element, which for me is the edge of the screen. However I don't want my images to be larger than 800px and otherwise react to the size of the window. I've accomplished that with the image. I've been trying to figure out how to make the next and prev arrows to stay "sticky" to the border of the img, and not to the div.  This is also my first post. So please let me know if there is a better way to format questions here. Thanks for your help.

```
HTML

<!-- Container for the image gallery -->
<div class="container">


  <!-- Full-width images with number text -->
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 6</div>
      <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/8260849/Woody_Front_P.png" class="slideimage">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 6</div>
      <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/8260849/Woody_Front_D.png" class="slideimage">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 6</div>
      <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/8260849/Woody_D_Side.png" class="slideimage">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">4 / 6</div>
      <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/8260849/Woody_Rear_P.png" class="slideimage">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">5 / 6</div>
      <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/8260849/Woody_Interior.png" class="slideimage">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">6 / 6</div>
      <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/8260849/Woody_dashboard.png" class="slideimage">
    
  </div>

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

 
  
  <!-- Image text -->
  <div class="caption-container">
    <p id="caption"></p>
  </div>

  <!-- Thumbnail images -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://assets.codepen.io/8260849/Woody_Front_P.png" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="1941 Packard Woody Passenger Side Front">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://assets.codepen.io/8260849/Woody_Front_D.png" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="1941 Packard Woody Driver Side Front">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://assets.codepen.io/8260849/Woody_D_Side.png" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="1941 Packard Woody Driver Side">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://assets.codepen.io/8260849/Woody_Rear_P.png" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="1941 Packard Woody Passenger Side Rear">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://assets.codepen.io/8260849/Woody_Interior.png" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(5)" alt="1941 Packard Woody Interior">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://assets.codepen.io/8260849/Woody_dashboard.png" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(6)" alt="1941 Packard Woody Dashboard">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- End code for Slideshow -->
  
  
</body>
```

```
CSS

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Position the image container (needed to position the left and right arrows) */
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.slideimage {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
}

/* Add a pointer when hovering over the thumbnail images */
.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 20%;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev {
  left: 20%;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* Container for image text */
.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #222;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Six columns side by side */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 16.66%;
}

/* Add a transparency effect for thumnbail images */
.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I set the div containing it to have the same width settings as the image.

```
CSS

/* Position the image container (width no longer 100%, now it matches the width of the image it contains) */
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.slideimage {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
```